# Apache pulsar java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, apache-pulsar

I'm working on a apache pulsar cluster and it was working fine, but for some reason I started getting the following message when I try to send a message:

`ERROR [id: 0xc5de4911, L:/127.0.0.1:55672 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:6650] Close connection becaues received internal-server error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive`

Also i'm getting the following error:

```
persistent://global/mycluster-cluster1/ns1/topic-partition-0] [null] Error connecting to broker: org.apache.pulsar.client.api.PulsarClientException$LookupException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /loadbalance/brokers/ip-11-55-123-80.ec2.internal:8080
```

I know the topic is created because i doble checked it using the pulsar-admin cli. I'm lost on where to start looking anyone could point me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the error message, it seems to be a race condition when Pulsar splits a namespace bundle. What version of Pulsar are you using?

Comment: 1.22.0-incubating is the condition i'm using

Comment: Try using a newer version of Pulsar.